# Data-structure design for Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

There is a ton of articles about structuring Firebase data, but mostly for messaging / product view apps and I believe my case is rather special. Also, I did it wrong few times, so I'm seeking help this time.

My app is for choosing babies name, written in Ionic 2 / Angular 2 and **flow is like this**:

1. You login (Facebook)
2. Choose multiple lists of names (like most popular in 2016, traditional names...)
3. See all names from all lists you have chosen and swiping names to another your lists ('favorites' <- 'unsorted' -> 'disliked')
4. Share your favorites/disliked/unsorted list to your partner and he/she can sort again

**What do I need to do?**

In my key view with names, I need to show a user list of names, sort them, search and be able to change names belonging from user list 'unsorted' to 'favorites'/'disliked'. If I change a view to 'favorites', I need to do the same but transfer names to the two others lists.

**My data structure might be like:**

```
* UserList (depends on Facebook login)
    - User UID
        - name: 'FutureParent'
        - UsersUnsortedList: List UID
        - UsersFavouriteList: List UID
        - UsersDislikedList: List UID
        - properties
            - preferedLanguage: 'en' 
            ...

*UsersListOfNames (every user has its own)
    - UserList UID
        - belongsToUser: User UID
        - namesContained:
            - name 1 UID: 'true' 
            - name 2 UID: 'true'   

* Default list of names (admin added, read only)
    - DefaultListofNames UID
        - listProperties
            - icon: 'star'
            - listName: 'Traditional Klingon Names' 
            ...
        - names
            - name 1 UID: true
            - name 2 UID: false

* Names (admin added, read only)
     - name 1 UID
         - name: 'Peter'
         - nameHistory: 'Comes from whatever region ...'
         - belongsToDefaultList:
            - listID: DefaultListofNames UID 1 
            - text2: DefaultListofNames UID 2
     - name 2 UID
         ...
```

Did I get flattening right? Is this suitable design?

Thanks a lot